# How to bind new button to a list of buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to dynamically add buttons to a list in WPF. After doing some research I came to this piece of code:

```
   <Button Content="Add New Button"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding AddNewButton}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonsList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Title}"
                    Margin="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Then I want to write something on the code to make this work.. since all answers I found about this only include the XAML for the solution, and not the code behind. I come from a web background so I'm totally new to WPF.. but I am thinking something like this:

```
public void AddNewButton(){
 ButtonsList.add({title='New button Title});
}
```

I know the syntax is wrong, I just wanted to try to express the code I'm thinking of.. something simple.. How could this work?

Comment: when you add an item into ButtonList, ItemControl will create a Button for you (because it is a Button in ItemTemplate). But ButtonList should better be `ObservableCollection<>`, not a simple `List<>` because `ObservableCollection<>` notifies UI when items were changed

Comment: so I would declare ButtonList as an ObservableCollecition?

Comment: well, yes, it certanly won't do harm. ObservableCollecition and INotifyPropertyChanged interface are two main WPF things to notify WPF UI about any changes in your data

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it could be:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="SO40212766.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO40212766"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding x:Name="AddNewButtonBinding" Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AddNewButton}" CanExecute="AddNewButtonBinding_CanExecute" Executed="AddNewButtonBinding_Executed" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
    <DockPanel>
    <Button Content="Add New Button" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AddNewButton}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonsList}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SO40212766
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      ButtonsList = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
    }

    public static RoutedUICommand AddNewButton = new RoutedUICommand("Add Button", "AddNewButton", typeof(MainWindow));

    public ObservableCollection<Button> ButtonsList { get; private set; }

    private void AddNewButtonBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    int index = 1;
    private void AddNewButtonBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // You will of course set the command og click event on the button here...
      ButtonsList.Add(new Button() { Content = $"Button {index++}" });
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** From the ItemsControl I have removed the ItemTemplate. You can then style the buttons in a style the way you want.

And be aware of the DataContext of the ItemsControl.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the MVVM pattern when dealing with WPF.

First you need a base class, that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` that is used by WPF for binding notification:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>( ref T backingField, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
        {
            return SetProperty<T>( ref backingField, newValue, EqualityComparer<T>.Default, propertyName );
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>( ref T backingField, T newValue, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
        {
            if ( comparer.Equals( backingField, newValue ) ) return false;

            backingField = newValue;
            RaisePropertyChanged( propertyName );
            return true;
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>( ref T backingField, T newValue, IComparer<T> comparer, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
        {
            if ( comparer.Compare( backingField, newValue ) == 0 ) return false;

            backingField = newValue;
            RaisePropertyChanged( propertyName );
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

For Buttons you need an `ICommand` so we are building a base class for implementing that

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
    {

        public virtual event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public virtual bool CanExecute( object parameter )
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute( object parameter )
        {
            if ( CanExecute( parameter ) )
                DoExecute( parameter );
        }

        protected abstract void DoExecute( object parameter );

    }
}
```

Next class is the `RelayCommand` inherited from `CommandBase`

```
using System;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class RelayCommand : CommandBase
    {

        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canexecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public RelayCommand( Action<object> execute ) : this( execute, o => true )
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand( Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canexecute )
        {
            if ( execute == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( execute ) );
            if ( canexecute == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( canexecute ) );

            _execute = execute;
            _canexecute = canexecute;
        }

        public override bool CanExecute( object parameter )
        {
            return base.CanExecute( parameter ) && _canexecute( parameter );
        }

        protected override void DoExecute( object parameter )
        {
            _execute( parameter );
        }

    }
}
```

Now we have a small base, we can work on. The Buttons should execute something and have a Text that will be displayed. So we define a ViewModel class that will represent this

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModel
{
    public class CommandViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        private ICommand command;
        private string displayText;

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return command; }
            set { SetProperty( ref command, value ); }
        }

        public string DisplayText
        {
            get { return displayText; }
            set { SetProperty( ref displayText, value ); }
        }

    }
}
```

Next we need a ViewModel that holds the list and the **Add** command

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            AddNewCommand = new CommandViewModel
            {
                DisplayText = "Add",
                Command = new RelayCommand( DoAddNewCommand )
            };

            Commands = new ObservableCollection<CommandViewModel>();
        }

        public CommandViewModel AddNewCommand { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<CommandViewModel> Commands { get; }

        private void DoAddNewCommand( object obj )
        {
            Commands.Add( new CommandViewModel
            {
                DisplayText = "Foo",
                Command = new RelayCommand( DoFoo ),
            } );
        }

        private void DoFoo( object obj )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Now it is time to bind all of it in the XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button
                Content="{Binding Path=AddNewCommand.DisplayText}"
                Command="{Binding Path=AddNewCommand.Command}"/>

            <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            Content="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"
                            Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                            Margin="2"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, there is no CodeBehind at all. Everything is done inside the ViewModels and the View is just presenting.